# store and execute redirection/piped command in script

Tags: shell, scripting, io-redirection, pipe

How do you store, and later execute, a command with redirection and and a pipe? (And is it the pipe, or the redirection, or both, that's causing my problem?)

I tried to print the urxvt version in a script, as well as echo the actual command.

The command I use to get the version is `urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2` - for some reason, urxvt prints help to `stderr`; as for the `head`, only the two first rows contain version and configuration data.

In the shell, it works great, but, in the script (isolated the problem, below), it seems the third line loses its head:

```
#!/bin/bash

VER_URXVT='urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2'
echo $VER_URXVT
$VER_URXVT
```

Comment: You probably meant to use backticks: ` instead of single quotes: ' - their meaning is quite different.

Comment: @RahulPatil: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @peterph: What I can see, that doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need the third line if you use backticks.

Comment: `echo $VER_URXVT | bash`

Comment: @ire_and_curses: First, it doesn't work with backticks, second, I want the third (and second) line -- that's the point of the question, to store a command, and be able to either echo it, or invoke it, later.

Comment: @RahulPatil: I'm not reading any more of your comments, if and when you get it to work, write a proper answer.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg , sorry that's back-tick issue . when i use back-tick over back-tick then it's not shown as expected that why i tried it again and again.

Comment: Of course 'it works' with backticks. But that evaluates the expression immediately, which apparently is not what you want (although that is not at all clear from your example). The `eval` solution provided is the correct way to defer execution until a later date.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Next time you guys have a bulletproof solution, why don't you just write a proper answer and be done with it? But, OK, I'm sure it works the way you have the solution drawn up in your head, I'm not doubting that. But, look at the guy below, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the eval expression

```
#!/bin/bash

VER_URXVT='urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2'
echo $VER_URXVT
eval $VER_URXVT
```

From the man page eval

```
          The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single com-
          mand.  This command is then read and executed by the shell,  and
          its  exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are
          no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks not only for your solution, but also for you taking your time understanding the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
VER_URXVT=`urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2`
```

which is the same as:

```
VER_URXVT=$(urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2)
```

to get the first two lines of `urxvt` help into `VER_URXVT`.

If you want to evaluate the command in shell variable, you should use `eval`:

```
VER_URXVT='urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2'
eval $VER_URXVT
```

Answer (score 3):

I keep on thinking functions are better than `eval`uing variables

```
#!/bin/bash

version() { uname -a;}
wm() { head -n1 <(openbox --version);}
for f in $(compgen -A function)
do declare -f $f | sed '1,2d; $d'
   $f
done
```

Comment: Hi Watael , nice info, if possible put comment :)

Answer (score 2):

don't ever use `eval` unless you really know what will be `eval`ed.

instead use a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

ver_urxvt() { urxvt -help 2>&1 | head -n 2;}
declare -f ver_urxvt | sed '1,2d; $d'
ver_urxvt
```

but it's silly, as it is a waste of time to print those informations.

if you want to debug your script use the `-x` option of the `set` builtin

Comment: You can take a look at the [script](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/scripts/sysinfo) in which I need this. So you see, individual functions is not an option. As for what you think is silly or not, that's irrelevant as this is a Q&A site. Downvote.

Comment: @UlrichDangel: When I said I needed it, that referred to a general solution, as opposed to individual functions for all commands. As for `eval`, I don't know how that differs from backticks/`$()`, but if you care to explain why it is considered unsafe, sure, I'll change it.

Comment: You ask.
I answer.
The answer **is** an opinion on how things should be handled, instead of your non-working, and counter-productive idea.
Q&A can also show what are best practices, and tell what are worst.
btw:
no "hi", no "please", no "thanks"... do you think we owe you something?
learn to live with others, that'll improve your coding too.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?! 1. The script works exactly as intended with the `eval` solution, 2. ... which I thanked, if you read the comment above, 3. the moderators frequently remove greetings, so I've stopped using them, although I fail to see how that's a big issue, and 4. do you actually expect me to thank you after calling my question silly, and my wish to print information "a waste of time"?

Comment: ah, ok! you misunderstood me: you don't waste my time, you uselessly occupy the resources of the machine for printing such informations.

Comment: (printing on screen is really resource consuming, and slows script execution; it wastes time, that's what I meant). Don't you do so to debug your script? to see what it does, when, etc? Then `set -x` is probably better.

Comment: OK, I see, haha :) The purpose of the script, if you check out the link in the first comment, is to create a text file with some info on the system. I'll refer to that file when someone asks for example "What window manager do you use?", also, I print the commands so that that person can see not only the information, but also the exact way by which I got it.